# Contact form validation issue

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation

I've made a PHP contact form for a client and they've come back to me saying they are receiving blank emails like this:

```
From: 
E-Mail: 
Message:
```

I've put JavaScript validation in place which successfully refuses a blank form when I submit the form in the standard way.

- What could be happening? Are we talking something malicious or stupid?
- What extra checks should I put in place? Are PHP checks a standard thing?

Code included below. Thanks in advance :)

JS validation:

```
  $("form#submit").submit(function() {   
    var custname = $('#custname').attr('value');  
    var custemail = $('#custemail').attr('value');  
    var custmessage = $('#custmessage').attr('value');

    if (custname==null || custname=="" || custemail==null || custemail=="" || custmessage==null || custmessage=="") {
      alert("Please fill out the whole form");
      return false;
  }
```

PHP mailer page:

```
<?php
$to = "name@email.com";
$subject = "Message from website";
$name_field = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['custname']));
$email_field = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['custemail']));
$message = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['custmessage']));

$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message: $message";

mail($to, $subject, $body);
?>
```

Comment: Well maybe people have simply disabled JavaScript. If blanks are not valid, you need to check on the server. You **always** need to check **everything** on the server.

Comment: Also note that you're not trimming spaces in your validation code!

Comment: Also note that you've probably got a perfectly lovely brain :-)

Comment: What about the HTML - Just because your elements' IDs match those given as keys to the `$_POST` array does not mean that their `name` attributes are identical. Your form elements need to have their `name` attributes match the keys of the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Are *all* of the messages empty, or is it just a few?

Comment: maybe they are calling the action page directly?you should always validate server side

Comment: Just a few are empty. The page works fine with normal usage - HTML form elements match.

Pointy's explanation sounds likely.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. My brain is happy with your comment

Comment: If javascript is the only form validation you have, then you don't have any form validation.  Javascript can be turned off, some browsers don't support it (like lynx and other line-mode brosers) and you don't even have to use a browser at all (try connecting to port 80 of any website you like with a simple Telnet client and send a GET / command).  Never forget that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP mailer page, you can write something like:-

```
<?php
// Site Name ( not Site Title )
$dotcom = "Custom Site Name";

$main_mail_arr            = array();
$main_mail_arr['admin']   = 'name@email.com';
$main_mail_arr['noReply'] = 'no-reply@email.com';
$main_mail_arr['cc']      = 'cc@email.com';
$main_mail_arr['bcc']     = 'bcc@email.com';

/**
 * Mail Function
 */
function genMailing($to, $subj, $body, $from = '', $fromName = '', $reply = true, $cc = '', $bcc = '') {
    global $main_mail_arr, $dotcom;

    if( empty( $from ) )
        $from = $main_mail_arr['noReply'];

    if( empty( $fromName ) )
        $fromName = $dotcom;

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $fromName <" . $from . ">\r\n";

    if( $reply )
        $headers .= "Reply-to: $fromName <" . $from . ">\r\n";

    if( !empty( $cc ) )
        $headers .= "Cc: " . $cc . "\r\n";

    if( !empty( $bcc ) )
        $headers .= "Bcc: " . $bcc . "\r\n";

    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n";

    $return_str = mail( $to, $subj, $body, $headers );
    return $return_str;
}

/**
 * Email Validation Function
 */
function checkEmail( $email, $type = true ) {
    if(preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/i", $email)) {
        $validResult = true;
    }

    if($validResult && $type) {
        $e = explode("@", $email);

        if(@checkdnsrr($e[1])) {
            $validResult = true;
        }
        else {
            $validResult = false;
        }
    }

    return $validResult;
}

if (isset( $_POST['custname'] ) && isset( $_POST['custemail'] ) && isset( $_POST['contact_msg'] )) {
    $nameError = '';
    $emailError = '';
    $msgError = '';

    $valName = trim( $_POST['custname'] );
    $valEmail = trim( $_POST['custemail'] );
    $valMsg = trim( $_POST['custmessage'] );

    if( empty( $valName ) ) {
        $nameError = 'Please provide your Name.';
    }

    if( !empty($valEmail) && !checkEmail($valEmail, false) ) {
        $emailError = 'Please provide your valid Email Address.';
    }

    if( empty( $valMsg ) ) {
        $msgError = 'Please provide your Message / Query / Comments.';
    }

    if( empty( $nameError ) && empty( $emailError ) && empty( $msgError ) ) {
        $to = $main_mail_arr['admin'];
        $subject = "Message from website";

        $body = '<h2 style="padding-bottom:0px; margin-bottom:0px;">New Details</h2>'.'<hr /><br />'."\r\n\n";
        $body .= '<b>Name</b>: '.stripslashes($valName).'<br />'."\n";
        $body .= '<b>Email Address</b>: '.stripslashes($valEmail).'<br />'."\n";
        $body .= '<b>Message</b>: '.stripslashes($valMsg).'<br />'."\n";

        $result = genMailing($to, $subject, $body, $valEmail, $valName, true);

        if ($result) {
            // Message for successful mail sent
        }
    }
    else {
        // Show the form below, with the error messages stored in the error variables
    }
}
?>
```

This above code mostly covers the server side validation, along with the Email Validation. However, you can also provide more stringent Email Validation checks than the one which I have used, and [Captcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) checking as well.

Although, the above code has served me well for quite some years, **it must be mentioned that this snippet is not the last & full-proof, as I have not used any filter / sanitization (like what WordPress or other CMSs do) for all the user inputs**. But nevertheless, it should get you well started with Google when dealing with user inputs.

You can also check out some of the below links for filter / sanitize:-

- [Sanitize and Validate Data with PHP Filters](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters/)
- [Filtering Data with PHP](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html)
- [Getting Clean With PHP](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/getting-clean-with-php/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for the detailed sample. I suggest also checking http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html for ready self-contained component.

Comment: @Laith - Thanks & agree with you. It's better to rely on the framework based written modules.

Answer (score 2):

Any validation occurs on client-side (Javascript) can by bypassed easily, for example by inspecting your page using FireBug.

Validation are used on client-side only for UX (user-experience) to make the user's life easier and faster. So in terms of real validation/security we need to do it again in the server-side (PHP).

In addition this current PHP code is opened to ['E-mail Injection'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_injection). You can check this question to make it secure [Escape string to use in mail()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071916/escape-string-to-use-in-mail).

In validation/security email stuff, it is better to rely on already well-written/well-tested module such as [Pear Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) OR [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html).