# Are to, subject and body safe against injection using mail()?

Tags: php, email, security

I have read the following comment in the official documentation of php about [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function:

> *Although it is not documented, for the parameters $to and $subject the mail() function changes at least \r and \n to space. So these parameters are safe against injection of additional headers. But you might want to check $to for commas as these separate multiple addresses and you might not want to send to more than one recipient.*

Is it correct? Also, I have always considered the $message parameter safe against injection, is it also correct?

I know how to protect myself against injection, I just want to know if I can avoid to filter those parameters.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by injection. If you let the user give values for the recipient, of course they can give whatever values they want.

Comment: Duplicated with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071916/escape-string-to-use-in-mail

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen no, I mean injection of additional headers (email injection vulnerability).

Comment: @ĐàoMinhHạt it is not a duplicate, I know how to protect myself against injection, I just want to know if I can avoid to filter those parameters.

Comment: If you're familiar enough with C to follow the logic, you can see exactly what is replaced here: http://lxr.php.net/source/xref/PHP-MASTER/ext/standard/mail.c#284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's true, but it's also incomplete. In the engine source code, the function [`php_mail_build_headers`](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/standard/mail.c#L186-L281) ensures headers comply with [RFC 2822 § 3.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6) requirements for maximum number of values. Particularly, the following headers are checked for single value:

- `orig-date`
- `from`
- `sender`
- `reply-to`
- `to`
- `bcc`
- `message-id`
- `in-reply-to`
- `subject`

Yes, the message parameter is safe from header injection by definition: the message part is inserted after the separating new line between headers and body, so any header-like text inserted as part of the message will appear as literal text within the message body.

Answer (score 0):

For your comment that you don't want to apply those filters.

I think you can get it done automatically by using [`Zend_Mail`](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-mail/) as I commented.

```
$ composer require zendframework/zend-mail
```

I'm pasting this from their [documentation](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-mail/transport/intro/):

```
use Zend\Mail\Message;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail as SendmailTransport;

$message = new Message();
$message->addTo('matthew@example.org');
$message->addFrom('ralph@example.org');
$message->setSubject('Greetings and Salutations!');
$message->setBody("Sorry, I'm going to be late today!");

$transport = new SendmailTransport();
$transport->send($message);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not an answer to my question.